# How can I reload CollectionView data in struct function?

Tags: swift

I'm try to reduce my main controller functions with using struct functions. In this point I have request to get data from server (its working fine) and after that function I reloaded collection view data. But when I try to reload data in struct it didn't working after that I tried to reload collection view in main controller but it was also not working. How can I make it?

**Here my struct to get data from server:**

```
struct ApiConnector {
    
    func getStructData(){
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://linklinklink")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil{
                
                do{
                    ViewController.urunlerArr = try JSONDecoder().decode([urunModel].self, from: data!)
                }catch{
                    print("sorun var ")
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(ViewController.urunlerArr)
                    // I TRIED HERE BUT IT WAS NOT WORKING...
                    //self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

**And here my main controller function:**

```
var apiStr = ApiConnector()

func getDataMainController(){
    
    apiStr.getStructData()
    // I TRIED HERE BUT IT WAS NOT WORKING..

}
```

Here my Collection View delegate method at Main Controller:

```
// MARK: MAIN VIEWCONTROLLER DELEGATES..

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ViewController.urunlerArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.urunAdiLabel.text = ViewController.urunlerArr[indexPath.row].name
        cell.fiyatLabel.text = "₺" + String(ViewController.urunlerArr[indexPath.row].price)
        cell.productImageView.downloaded(from: ViewController.urunlerArr[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
        var adetCount = 0
        cell.adetLabel.text = String(adetCount)
        cell.urunCikarButton.isHidden = true
        cell.adetLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.urunEkleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ekleAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.urunEkleButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.urunCikarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cikarAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.urunCikarButton.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong from here, can you try to share more code? Like the delegate functions and the more code from your viewcontroller?

Comment: Collection View delegate methods? I can share but is it solve reload collection view data from struct?

Comment: This cannot as your are using a class method (ViewController.reloadData()) . As specified by Luca Sfragara you should have delegate methods to enable accès to the collection view of the view controller instance from your struct.

Comment: I added Collection View delegate methods now. It placed main controller.

Comment: I think you need a `completionHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer the data from a `struct` to an another class or `viewController` class. Also, this is an `async` request, so you have to use completionHandler.

```
struct ApiConnector {
    
    func getStructData(completion: @escaping(_ arr: YourModel?, _ error: Error?) -> Void){
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://linklinklink")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error { completion(nil, error); return }  
                
            do {
               let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([urunModel].self, from: data!)
              
                 completion(array, nil)
              
            } catch {
                 completion(nil, error)
               
            }
             
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

In you `mainViewController`:

private var apiStr = ApiConnector()
private var storeArray = YourModel() //Use your model here

```
func getDataMainController(){
    
    apiStr.getStructData() { [weak self] (array, error) in 

        if let error = error { //Display Alert  return }

        if let array = array { 
          self?.storeArray = array
          self?.collectionV.reloadData()
        }
    } 


}
```

Then, in your `collectionViewDelegate`:

```
// MARK: MAIN VIEWCONTROLLER DELEGATES..

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storeArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.urunAdiLabel.text = storeArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.fiyatLabel.text = "₺" + String(ViewController.urunlerArr[indexPath.row].price)
        cell.productImageView.downloaded(from: storeArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
        var adetCount = 0
        cell.adetLabel.text = String(adetCount)
        cell.urunCikarButton.isHidden = true
        cell.adetLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.urunEkleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ekleAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.urunEkleButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.urunCikarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cikarAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.urunCikarButton.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    }
```

Also, I will suggest you to use `if let` and you can use better names for understanding purpose.

P.S.: If you don't know what a completion handler is then, please check this [link to understand what a completion handler is and why we use them](https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/completion-handler-swift-199a5a08d8e6)

Comment: Please, `_ arr: YourModel?, _ error: Error?` with underscore and parameter label is outdated Swift 2 legacy code. Why not modern`Result<YourModel,Error>`?

Comment: @vadian I use `Result`, but I though that the user who asked the question is beginner so I added this instead of `Result`.